# Name 'run' is assigned to before global declaration

Tags: python

Im very new to python having worked on languages like C++ and C# previously and dont understand the error that the compiler is throwing at me.

Im trying to create a global bool to stop the threaded function when it is changed to false.

my code so far is:

```
import random
import math
import threading
import time

listOfParticles = []
listOfThreads = []
run = False


def printList():
    print("New List :")
    for i in listOfParticles:
        print(str(i[0]) + "," + str(i[1]))

def moveParticle(partID):
    while (True):
        if(run == False): return
        else:
            dir = random.randrange(0,360)
            dist = random.random()
            distx = math.cos(math.radians(dir))*dist
            disty = math.sin(math.radians(dir))*dist
            listOfParticles[i][0] += distx
            listOfParticles[i][1] += disty

def startMove():
    global run
    run = True
    for i in range(len(listOfParticles)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=moveParticle, args=(i,))
        listOfThreads.append(t)
    
    for i in listOfThreads:
        i.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    global run
    for i in range(10):
        listOfParticles.append([random.random(), random.random()])
    startMove()
    while(run):
        printList()
        time.sleep(0.001)
    run = False
```

And this code is giving me the error

```
  File "d:\Programming\repos\Parallel\repos\Python\Lab 4\threadedParticles.py", line 38
    global run
    ^
SyntaxError: name 'run' is assigned to before global declaration
```

What confuses me is that the error is happening on the global definition.

Comment: No, this code gives `NameError: name 'false' is not defined`. Please provide the right code that produces the error you say it does.

Comment: The posted code has multiple references to `true` and `false`, which you have not defined.  Python defines `True` and `False`, but not their lowercase versions.  What code are you actually running?

Comment: @TomKarzes i have edited it to fix that, after using one of the answers on here i fixed my error and then spotted the true/false problem and fixed that too

Comment: @watsom27 No, you fixed some references.  Some remain.  I see `run = false` and `run = true`.  Can you not see that?

Comment: `name 'random' is not defined`, then `name 'startMove' is not defined`... Please take time to write a correct, answerable question by providing the **exact**, **runnable** code, not some version of it that doesn't work the way you say it does.

Comment: @TomKarzes sorry, my bad in editing the code on here

Comment: Please don't edit it. Run your code, check the output, then copy and paste it at once, with the matching error message.

Comment: @watsom27 That's why you always copy/paste the *actual* code, rather than trying to recreate it in the Stack Overflow editor.

Comment: i did copy and paste the actual code, @ThierryLathuille those errors were caused by me doing the markdown wrong on stack overflow so it missed the first import statement

Comment: `name 'startMove' is not defined` . Oh please.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille it turns out that i had several errors in the code that showed up once i fixed the global definition error. Ive fixed the rest of the code and left the global error in, which when removed (as stated in the accepted answers) fixes the error

Comment: I can confirm the last comment from OP, his code has obvious Python errors and it clearly looks like OP updated his code without running it, but even with that my answer still address the issue and answer his original question

Comment: @Arount correct, the code now runs and does what i expect it to, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `global` here.

Your code within `if __name__ == "__main__":` is in the same scope as `run = False` since it's not a function but just a regular `if` condition.